# Unable to connect to Kafka run in container from Spring Boot app run outside container

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm running kafka locally via:

docker-compose.yml

```
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

My Spring Boot application is run with:

application.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: testkafka
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092

server:
  port: 8080
```

When I run it and it tries to send to a topic on kafka, I get:

```
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Reply timed out
    at org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.ReplyingKafkaTemplate.lambda$sendAndReceive$0(ReplyingKafkaTemplate.java:196) ~[spring-kafka-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

If I run the spring boot from inside a docker container (using one docker compose file), then it *does* work:

Running Both in the Same Compose:

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  service1:
    build: ./Service
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 5005:5005
    links:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

How can I get the kafka container to allow connections from outside itself/docker?

**EDIT: Tried these changes:**

```
kafka:
  image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
  ports:
    - 9092:9092
  environment:
    - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
    - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
    - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
```

and:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: testkafka
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: kafka:9092

server:
  port: 8080
```

This still times out

Comment: This question is asked rather repeatedly. Please read https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If I run the spring boot from inside a docker container (using one docker compose file), then it does work

It shouldn't work, actually. Kafka isn't running as part of the application, so this section is not pointing at the Kafka container.

```
kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
```

It would need to be `kafka:9092` within the Docker network.

> and ... `bootstrap-servers: kafka:9092` ... still times out

That's because you still have `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092`

---

Both inside and outside of Docker network, by specifying `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092`, you're saying that your clients receive the Kafka bootstrap connection as `localhost:9092`, which would work outside of the Docker network only because you have made both a port forwarding and your container is running on localhost, however, inside the Docker network, as mentioned, localhost would mean *that* application container, not the broker.

The solution would be to create two port mappings via that property, as discussed in length by [this blog post](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/)

Plus, [Confluent provides a fully configured Docker Compose](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/5.0.0-post/examples/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml) with appropriate mappings that'll work inside and out of Docker

```yaml
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: "yes"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:29092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
```

For applications within Docker network, use `kafka:9092`, for applications outside, use **`localhost:29092`**

**EDIT** The bitnami config variables have changed. Refer this section of the README

https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka/blob/master/README.md#accessing-kafka-with-internal-and-external-clients

Comment: in addition to Cricket answer you can then add `kafka` in your host file and connect to it from out side the docker-compose, given `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092`, `bootstrap-servers: kafka:9092` and `ports - 9092:9092`

Comment: @Paizo Editing the hosts file is a hack, and should be avoided. Correcting the listeners is the correct thing.

Comment: @DonRhummy See updated answer. The gist here is that you can't have the same spring config working inside and outside of Docker

Comment: @cricket_007 I get the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: advertised.listeners listener names must be equal to or a subset of the ones defined in listeners. Found PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST. The valid options based on the current configuration are PLAINTEXT`

Comment: @DonRhummy Have you defined `KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP`, as mentioned in my answer?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes. I believe the issue is with the bitnami image. Can you try it yourself?

Comment: @DonRhummy Fixed. See updated answer. The consumer seemed to kill the container on the first request, but restarting the container, I saw the messages

Comment: @cricket_007 If you can add `ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: "yes"` I'll mark this as the answer. Without that it fails.